# Accessing websites - JScript, VBScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, vbscript

Trying to write a windows speech recognition macro. In writing macros, scripting can be done with either JScript or VBScript. I have found that certain websites are inaccesible, to be fetched data from, when scripting via JScript (except for RSS feeds which works fine for me). Question is, does the same problem exist for VBScripting ? I learnt JScript only for writing these macros, and now that it cant access web pages, I am thinking of giving VBScript a try. But if the same problem exists for VBScript, then I'd rather not waste time.

Help ? :)

Comment: You need to add way more detail about *how* those sites are inaccessible exactly. There is a number of ways how that could happen (although my guess would be that they generate a big portion of their content through Ajax, something that a normal crawler can't catch.)

Comment: Say I am trying to get the length of a particular string from a webpage. If the webpage is an rss feed, the value gets returned correctly. If not, that is say a page like Wikipedia, the returned value is null.

Comment: I think you will need to show some real-life code. This could have any number of reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which script engine probably does not matter. If the underlying platform denies acces for some security policy reasons, or for whatever else, then another scripting language will not help. Remember, these are only *scripting* languages; they actually don't contain any networking capabilities, they just provide you access to the platform. For example, the same ActiveX objects are available as well in JScript as in VBScript.